# Ajax add value to JSON to be graphed every second

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, flot

I have an Arduino via an Ethernet Shield printing out a value every second via AJAX. I would like to graph this value in [Flot](http://flotcharts.org). This requires the value to be put in a JSON format like this

```
[[epochtimestamp, value], [epochtimestamp, value]]
```

So I was wondering if you could help me use JavaScript/AJAX (or PHP if you think it is appropriate) to every second get this value and add it to the JSON inside the .txt file (used to store the previous values), so Flot can read all the values and create a time-based graph of these values but update the graph every second through AJAX.

Here is the basic process which needs to happen every second.

1. Arduino Updates Value (I've done that bit)
2. Javascript or PHP file which adds this value in to the JSON with a timestamp
3. Flot updates and graphs the new value.

Here is some code I have started but it would have to be called by AJAX every second and wouldn't do the entire job.

```
<?php
$file    = 'data.txt';
$webpage = 'test.txt';
$t       = time(); // Open the file to get existing content 
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$data    = file_get_contents($webpage);
// Append a new person to the file 
if ($current < 1) {
    $current .= "[[" + $t + "," + $data + "]";
} else {
    $current .= ", " + "[" + $t + "," + $data + "]";
} // Write the contents back to the file 
file_put_contents($file, $current);
echo $current;
?>
```

I'm not sure if it would be easier to do with Javascript/AJAX?

Comment: can you please post some code, if you use any?

Comment: Well I started using PHP to add it to a file etc but it would have to be called by AJAX every second.   
    <?php
$file = 'data.txt';
$webpage = 'test.txt'
$t = time();
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$data = file_get_contents($webpage)
// Append a new person to the file
if ($current < 1) {
 $current .= "[[" + $t + "," + $data + "]";
}
else {
 $current .= ", " + "[" + $t + "," + $data + "]";
}
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
echo $current;
?>

Comment: I'm also 15 and trying to learn so any suggestions etc or comments to help me are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the source of flot's [real-time updating example.](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/realtime/index.html)

You could call your PHP script via AJAX from the browser, your client code should look like the following.

```
// Initialize your empty plot
var plot = $.plot("#myPlot", [], {
  series: {
    shadowSize: 0 // Drawing is faster without shadows
  },
  yaxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100
  },
  xaxis: {
    show: false
  }
});

function update() {
    // Make an ajax call to your script to get data provided by your script
    // Which reads that data.txt from Arduino.
    $.ajax({
        url: "yourhost/yourscript.php",
        context: document.body
    }).done(function(response) {
        // Get the ajax response
        data = response;

        // If data is not null, set your plot's data.
        if (data != null)
            plot.setData(data);


        // Draw the plot.
        plot.draw();

        // Re-invoke update.
        update();
    });
}

// Initial call to the update func.
update();
```

Comment: Hmmm, it doesn't seem to work. I had to change null to 0, otherwise it had an error. But now the function getData() won't return anything but a 0. Inside the function getData(), I put document.write(data); and it printed out all the values. So it is not returning the values for use outside of the function?

Comment: This shouldnt be the exact code you are working on, the point is getting data with ajax and show it with flot. Keep working, I'll make a sample as soon as i have time :)

Comment: This code is wrong.  `$.ajax({` is async.  The `setData` and `plot.draw` need to occur in it's done handler.  The way this is coded getData will always return `null`.

Comment: Oh my god, what a stupid mistake. thanks @Mark. I've updated my answer, but had no time to try it, can you check it again now please?

Comment: I tried it but it won't work. It draws the plot without the axis and data points..? Also the setTimeout is missing from the code above so I had to put it back in. I know that AJAX is calling the PHP file every second, Flot just isn't graphing it?

Comment: You don't need to include setTimeout, as the function is invoked everytime an AJAX request returns... This isn't the complete code, you should improve and change it your way.